# Finding Multiple Data in a List

Tags: javascript

So basically I have a list like this:

```
var list = [[1, 4, 6], [1, 4, 5], [4, 7, 2]];
```

and I want to find the ones based on a list like this:

```
var search = [1, 4];
```

and from that it would return 
list[0] and list[1] because they both have one and four in it.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I could not come up with any ways of doing this.

Comment: Post an attempt please

Comment: So what did you try?

Comment: Do you know loop in programming?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `filter()` and `every()` methods.

```js
var list = [[1, 4, 6], [1, 4, 5], [4, 7, 2]];
var search = [1, 4];

const result = list.filter(a => search.every(e => a.includes(e)));
console.log(result)
```